# When establishing a BLE connection, can the first two data packets contain application data?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When a BLE device (M) is scanning and another one (S) is advertising, to create a connection M must send a CONNECT_REQ packet to S. Immediately, the connection is considered created.

In order to **establish** the connection, one data packet must be **sent** (by M) **and** **acknowledged**  (by S).

I noticed that generally this very first data packet exchange consists of **Empty PDU** packets.

Question: does the standard (4.1) allow these very first packets to also contain application data? (e.g. an ATT request)

Answer (score 0):

After long searches, it turns out it is indeed possible to send application data in the first two data packets.

The standard doesn't approve or deny explicitly this hypothesis, but Robin Heydon explains it in this book.